# How to combine render and composer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I make 2 scenes: first for objects, second for clone objects with EffectComposer(BloomPass,FilmPass). I trying make `renderer.render(scene,camera)` with `composer.render()` - but it is not work, the only one idea is:

```
var crazy = 1;
function render() {
if (crazy == 1) { renderer.render(scene, camera); crazy = 0; }
else { composer.render(); crazy = 1; 
}
```

How to combine the two renderers?

Comment: You need to render the output camera and scene of the effect composer itself if i remember correctly, as its probably filming a material with an orthographic cam to do the render passes.

Answer (score 0):

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-effectcomposer-layers/3158

Use layers and see more: http://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/mjfckw02/

Somsething like this(code prisoner849):

```
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.clear();
  
  camera.layers.set(1);
  composer.render();
  
  renderer.clearDepth();
  camera.layers.set(0);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```